# Cannot build solution after updating to Ranorex 9.1

Tags: c#, msbuild, ranorex

I recently upgraded my Ranorex to the newest (9.1). Since then Ranorex won't build the solution anymore. It always says `Build failed`. Followed by `Nothing to do. None of the projects in this solution specify any packages for NuGet restore.`

Does anyone no why this error occurs and how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try installing .Net Framework 4.6.2. This is what fixed it for me!

Older versions of .Net Framework or corrupted installations of 4.6.2 can cause build errors: 
https://www.ranorex.com/forum/compile-error-t14146.html